# Adding graphics views android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

This will be my first question, so I apologize for my probable mistakes.

I'm trying to add a red circle each time I press the button I've incorported to my layout. I'd like all circles stayed in the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                                    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"                                   
    android:orientation="vertical" >                                      

    <LinearLayout                                                         
        android:id="@+id/panelJuego"                                      
        android:layout_width="match_parent"                               
        android:layout_height="match_parent"                              
        android:layout_weight="0.76"                                      
        android:orientation="horizontal" >                                

    </LinearLayout>                                                       

    <Button                                                               
        android:id="@+id/button1"                                         
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"                            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                               
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                              
        android:onClick="botonRojo"                                       
        android:text="Button" />                                          
</LinearLayout>
```

The java code related with my trying is:

```
public void botonRojo(View v) {                                               
    LinearLayout panelJuego = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panelJuego);   
    PonCirculo circulo = new PonCirculo(this, 30, 30, "#FF0000");             
    circulo.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(                    
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                           
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));                         
    panelJuego.addView(circulo);                                              
}                                                                             


public class PonCirculo extends View {                                        
    private int radio = 30;                                                   
    private String color;                                                     
    public PonCirculo(Context context, int x, int y, String color) {          
        super(context);                                                       
        Cx = Cx + x;                                                          
        Cy = Cy + y;                                                          
        this.color = color;                                                   
    }                                                                         
    @Override                                                                 
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {                                    
        super.onDraw(canvas);                                                 
        Paint paint = new Paint();                                            
     paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);                                        
     paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));                                 
     canvas.drawCircle(Cx, Cy, radio, paint);                                 
 }
```

Actually each time I press the button a red filled circle appears in the android screen but when I press the button again a new circle appears and the fomer disappears. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, I meant "former", the former circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are just trying to add each circle under each other when the button is pressed.

Currently you are adding a new view each time now but it is over-laying the previous view. You need add the views giving each new circle a unique id. Then place the new circle underneath or whatever position you choose. I'm giving you some example code that I changed to use a relative layout and I place each circle under the previous one. This should get you started with what you are looking for:

Example Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeCircleLayout">

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Circle"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="botonRojo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Example Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<PonCirculo> viewList = new ArrayList<PonCirculo>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void botonRojo(View v) {
    RelativeLayout panelJuego = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeCircleLayout);
    PonCirculo circulo = new PonCirculo(this, 30, 30, "#FF0000");
    circulo.setId(View.generateViewId());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

    if(!viewList.isEmpty()) {
        int id = viewList.get(viewList.size()-1).getId();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id);
    }
    panelJuego.addView(circulo, params);
    viewList.add(circulo);
}


public class PonCirculo extends View {
    private int radio = 30;
    private String color;
    int Cx, Cy;

    public PonCirculo(Context context, int x, int y, String color) {
        super(context);
        Cx = Cx + x;
        Cy = Cy + y;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        canvas.drawCircle(Cx, Cy, radio, paint);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work totally right. First time I press button it appears a red circle, second time I press button the first red circle is shifted a little at right and a second red circle appears below it, third time  I press the button three quarter red circles appear lightly shifted to the right, each one below other, and fourth time I press the button all they disappear.

Comment: I've just  noticed that I haven't changed "Activity" to "AppCompatActivity". Could be that the reason for this difference?

Comment: I've just  noticed that I haven't changed "Activity" to "AppCompatActivity". Could be that the reason for this difference? I can't change it because I don't get import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity although I've yet installed the "Android Support Repository" via SDK

Comment: You are welcome. Can you accept the answer since it works for you? Thanks